# Are there any conjugate likelihood distributions for a Categorical Prior?

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior

I have the following generative process:

$$\begin{align}
z &\sim Cat(\pi)\\
o | z &\sim p(o|z)
\end{align}$$

I'd like to infer a posterior over $z$ i.e. $p(z|o)$. Thankfully, I have complete freedom in modeling the random variable $o$ and its emission distribution $p(o|z)$. Are there any conjugate likelihood distributions for the Categorical prior such that the resulting posterior $p(z|o)$ is also Categorical?

Edit 1: I need the resulting posterior to be exact. For instance, if the emission distribution depends on unknown parameters (e.g. each possible value of $z$ corresponds to a Gaussian mean and covariance), then the posterior $p(z|o)$ can only be computed iteratively using Expectation Maximization and maybe not converge to the correct posterior.

Answer (score 3):

**Any likelihood function will do this:** Since $Z \sim \text{Cat}(\pi)$, it is a discrete random variable with some finite number of possible states.  Regardless of the likelihood function, it will still be distributed over these same states *a posteriori* and so it will still have a categorical distribution.  This merely reflects the fact that *every distribution over a finite set of outcomes is a categorical distribution*.

If you would like an explicit result, you can just apply [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).  For any observed value $o$ giving likelihood $L_o$, the resulting posterior distribution is:

$$Z|o \sim \text{Cat}(\pi^{*})
\quad \quad \quad 
\pi_z^{*} \equiv \frac{L_o(z) \cdot \pi_z}{\sum_z L_o(z) \cdot \pi_z }.$$

Comment: I'm confused by this statement. Suppose I choose a Gaussian likelihood (so we have a mixture of Gaussians) where the Gaussian parameters per possible state are unknown. Isn't this exactly why we use algorithms like Expectation Maximization, because the posterior of the latent variable doesn't exist in closed form?

Comment: Even in this case there are only a finite number of possible values for $z$, so it is still a catagorical random variable.  So long as the number of possible values is not too large we could compute all the posterior probabilities directly.  (If it is too large for this to be computable then we have other problems.)

Comment: I agree that the posterior will always be a Categorical distribution. My concern is that the exact posterior is not available in closed form. Maybe I should have added that constraint to the question?

Comment: The exact posterior is written above, and is in closed form so long as the likelihood function $L_o$ is in closed form.

Comment: Suppose the likelihood is Gaussian with unknown mean $\mu_z$ and unknown covariance $\Sigma_z$ (i.e. two parameters per possible outcome from the Categorical distribution). How can the posterior be computed exactly?

Comment: This would be computed using Bayes' theorem, as shown in the formula in the answer.

Comment: ...specifically, it would be:
$$\pi_z^* = \frac{\text{det}(\Sigma^z)^{-1/2} \exp(-\tfrac{1}{2} (o-\mu_z)^\text{T} \Sigma_z^{-1} (o-\mu_z)) \cdot \pi_z}{\sum_z \text{det}(\Sigma^z)^{-1/2} \exp(-\tfrac{1}{2} (o-\mu_z)^\text{T} \Sigma_z^{-1} (o-\mu_z)) \cdot \pi_z},$$
where the sum in the denominator is taken over all allowable indices for $z$.

Comment: How do you propose calculating that above expression when $\Sigma^z$ and $\mu_z$ are unknown?

Comment: If these parameters are unknown for any given value $z$ then you no longer have a model of the form you have specified in your question (where the discrete parameter $z$ is the unknown parameter of the model).  Your questions suggest that you might have some confusion about the specification of your model.  May I recommend that you  have a bit of a think about the type of model of interest to you, and specifically, whether you are interested in the case where the unknown parameter is discrete with a known prior distribution (as in your question).